# How to write oracle hint in rails scope method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle-sqldeveloper

In my rails model I have a scope method

```
class User
  scope :failed,
    :select => %{
      /*+ some hint */ *
    } ,
    :joins => :address,
    :conditions => %{
      addresses.location_id IS NULL
    }
```

My problem is first is this the right way of introducing hint in scope method and second when I run `User.failed.count` it doesn't consider the hint. Please help

This is the sql generated when  I call `User.failed`

```
SELECT /*+ some hint */ * FROM "SOME_SCHEMA"."USERS" INNER JOIN "SOME_SCHEMA"."ADDRESSES" ON "SOME_SCHEMA"."ADDRESSES"."ID" = "SOME_SCHEMA"."USERS"."ADDRESS_ID" WHERE (addresses.location_id IS NULL)
```

and this is the sql generated when I call `User.failed.count`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "SOME_SCHEMA"."USERS" INNER JOIN "SOME_SCHEMA"."ADDRESSES" ON "SOME_SCHEMA"."ADDRESSES"."ID" = "SOME_SCHEMA"."USERS"."ADDRESS_ID" WHERE (addresses.location_id IS NULL)
```

Notice it skips the hint part.

Comment: Please include the sql code from your server

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio updated my question, hope that would help